# iPhone/ iPad serial communication using USB

Tags: iphone, ipad, serial-communication, usb-otg

I wish to create an app that allows serial data to be sent and received between Android and Apple tablets and phones. It has been decided that the data must be transmitted and received via the USB port of the tablet or phone. If this is not viable, I'll attempt to use Bluetooth.

**Question 1: Is there a way to communicate serially using an iDevice's USB port?** This data is to be interpreted in an app that will be sold on the app store.

My research so far has determined that on an Android phone this can be achieved by:

- Using a USB On The Go (OTG) cable
- Connecting this to a serial-to-usb converter cable
- Use the Android SDK including USB Host to read/ write via the USB port
- Create the app using many of the IDE and programming language options
- Upload it to google play with ease

Facilitating this same application on an iDevice seems less straight forward. What I've determined so far is:

- An apple certified USB-Serial or USB OTG cable must be used
- "Redpark" sell this product but it is restricted for non-commercial use
- A "Made for iPhone" licence is required to make any hardware for apple if I were to make my own cable
- A iOS developer licence is required to write the app

**Question 2: How much does MFi certification cost? This is not easy information to obtain.**

Sorry for the long-winded description but I wanted to show that I have made the effort to research this prior to asking a question.

Comment: It doesn't look like this ever got traction...I'm in the same boat as OP. 

I have a functioning version of my app on Android but that leaves about half of our clients unable to use our app. 

I'm now researching using the headphone jack on iOS. [Project HiJack](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/) I think it's called...did you ever have success on your end?

Comment: I just wrote the application for Android and am yet to even consider writing for Apple. If I do I'll just use Bluetooth and save the heartache. I considered the option of using the headphone jack but abandoned it as 1. My cable wouldn't supply enough current to power it and 2. Apple are abandoning the headphone jack and forcing consumers to use more proprietary apply hardware. I hope one day people comes to their senses and stop purchasing apple products.